# Django REST Framework serializer - turn id field into title while keeping the POST method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, serialization

I am creating a cart with a list of products. I am trying to turn my product ids into titles while still being able to use my POST/ PUT methods on the products to be able to add/ remove the products.

Previously my products in the cart was displayed as IDs, this was my serializer:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    url             = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
                            view_name='cart-api:cart-detail',
                            read_only=True,
                            lookup_field='id',
                            )
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = [
            "id",
            "url",
            "products",
            "sub_total",
            "shipping",
            "total",

        ]
```

[image]

After making some changes, I was able to turn the product ids into titles and several other fields related to each product. Here is my serializer code after the changes:

But my products disappeared from my put method and I am no longer able to add/ remove products. 
(snippet 2)

How can we keep the the POST/ PUT methods on my product while displaying them as the way I want in snippet 2? Thanks so much in advance!

```
class MyPaintingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    painting_url             = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
                                view_name='paintings-api:detail',
                                read_only=True,
                                lookup_field='slug'
                                )


    class Meta:
        model = Painting
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',  
            'painting_url',
            'price',                
        ]


class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    url             = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
                            view_name='cart-api:cart-detail',
                            read_only=True,
                            lookup_field='id',
                            )
    products     = MyPaintingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = [
            "id",
            "url",
            "products",
            "sub_total",
            "shipping",
            "total",
        ]
```

[image]

Here is my code for views.py

```
class CartListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset            = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = CartSerializer
    permission_classes  = [permissions.AllowAny]    

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryList = Cart.objects.all()

        cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id", None)

        return queryList


class CartDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset            = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = CartSerializer
    lookup_field        = 'id'   
    permission_classes  = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

Comment: you can try define other `serializer` for each method `PUT`, `POST`, `GET`. Like override `get_serializer_class` .Can you show your code of `Card-detail-Api`

Comment: @NgocPham Yes I have added my views.py code.